# .NET Winforms project with complex GUI and constraints between fields

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I work at a company that repairs stuff and each time they repair something they have to fill a paper with tables everywhere and tons of fields.
Now they want to get rid of the papers and they need an application that would replace the whole thing, and store the results in a db. For that I have to use C# with .NET and Windows Forms.
**The problem now** : there are ComboBoxes in this form whose values affect the behavior of other Controls. For example, if ComboBox1 has Value1, ComboBox2 available values to choose from will be Value2, Value3, Value6, ...
Also consider this :

```
╔════╦════════╗
║ OK ║ Not OK ║
╠════╬════════╬═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║    ║        ║ Measure 1 : ....... (threshold for Value1 : > 180cd/m²) ║
║ ∙  ║   ∘    ║                     (threshold for Value2 : > 130cd/m²) ║
║    ║        ║ Measure 2 : ....... (threshold for Value3 : > 100cd/m²) ║
╚════╩════════╩═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

The cells under 'OK' and 'Not OK' are RadioButtons. Until now (on the paper) they were checked manually according to the values of Measure 1 and 2. Now this is a Winforms app, they have to be checked automatically to lower the chance of errors. I don't think I'd have many problems with managing that, just by parsing string values and comparing them to the threshold. Where it gets real messy is that, as showned, the threshold is not always the same and changes with the values of the aforementionned ComboBoxes.

It sounds simple, and it would be if it was just that, but it's actually quite heavy because there's a lot of Controls being involved.
I'd like to know what is the most *elegant* and *efficient* way to manage all of these constraints between the Controls.

---

## What I have thought of so far

**The hard way :**
Callbacks everywhere. Whenever a value changes somewhere, a function is called and it does stuff to update the form. That means A LOT of dependancies across the Controls and also almost no evolution possible unless you want to rewrite the whole application.

**The less hard way :**
A db would store pretty much everything about the constraints, and whenever something important changes, a quick check through the db would allow you to know which controls to update and what to update in them. I'm not sure how I'm seeing this for the RadioButton and thresholds stuff, but for example, that would do the trick for the available values of ComboxBox2 being choosen by the value of ComboBox1 :

```
╔═════════════╗ ╔═══════════════════════╗
║ CB1_VALUES  ║ ║      CB2_VALUES       ║
╠═════════════╣ ╠═══════════╦═══════════╣
║ Values      ║ ║ CB1Values ║ CB2Values ║
╠═════════════╣ ╠═══════════╬═══════════╣
║ Value1      ║ ║ Value1    ║ Value4    ║
║ Value2      ║ ║ Value1    ║ Value5    ║
║ Value3      ║ ║ Value1    ║ Value6    ║
╚═════════════╝ ║ Value2    ║ Value7    ║
                ║ Value2    ║ Value8    ║
                ║ Value3    ║ Value3    ║
                ║ Value3    ║ Value6    ║
                ║ Value3    ║ Value9    ║
                ╚═══════════╩═══════════╝
```

Do a `"SELECT CB2Values FROM CB2_VALUES WHERE CB1Values = Value1"` and boom, here are your available values for ComboBox2 when ComboBox1 = Value1.
So in this case I think this is a fairly good idea, but I don't know at all how it could help for the threshold thing, neither am I able to come up with another idea...

Any help would appreciated ! :)

Comment: How do you know that you need to query db for a new state ?

Comment: It looks like you want to interweave the business logic, data access, and presentation layers all in one place. I would advise against this. Even with Winforms you can apply a MVVM or MVC pattern that binds the data to a view model. This would simplify your code quite a bit.

Comment: Why do you have to write a new app in winforms in 2015? why dont you just use WPF with MVVM and then in a nice and clean way move that binding logic to VM and let the view just represent the state?

Comment: @Tigran: callbacks I guess.

Comment: @zaitsman: I'm actually an intern and I am here for 4 weeks, I don't have the time to learn WPF and MVVM :/

Comment: @qreon: so you will need again a lot of callbacks, also in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The question is rather should configuration be declarative or imperative.

In my understanding you are going to write a small ERP which manages items, their state, availability in warehouse..etc. I would rather look for keeping state information in DB in this case, to avoid 2 different sources of information (data and configuration).

You need to store items state in DB in any case, so let's store also controls state there. Controls state is a crucial to make right, as it conditions health of your app. None of users will query database with `SQL`, most likely, but rather work with interface.

Would be better also on DB side have stored procedures, triggers that check state on every submit of data, or state change. This is an approach that usually follow giants like `SAP`, but may be applicable also in smaller cases, like yours, imo.

Comment: Someone recommended design pattern in the comments above, I'm gonna try that out because the Controls db things looks dirty after all.

Comment: @qreon: MVVM means call backs, from `UI` to model view, basically the first option you're writing about. If that's ok, go with that.

Comment: I don't know what I'm going for, but I will try things out. Thank you for your answers ! :)